# Where do I get the list of nameservers needed to create a DNS policy?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

there's a list of 10 steps recommended to be followed when setting up Google Cloud for one's organisation.  Step 8 "Setup network configuration" fails on account of:

> DNS server policies could not be loaded. If you need to pick a DNS server policy, try reloading the page.

(reloading the page doesn't solve anything).  So I've started looking into what it would take to set up a DNS policy and like everything else, it's a rabbit hole I don't have time for.  however this is the command I believe will create me a policy:

```
gcloud dns policies create NAME \
--description=DESCRIPTION \
--networks=VPC_NETWORK_LIST \
--alternative-name-servers=ALTERNATIVE_NAMESERVER_LIST \
--private-alternative-name-servers=PRIVATE_ALTERNATIVE_NAMESERVER_LIST \
--enable-inbound-forwarding
```

now my questions:

1. the values in caps I'm supposed to provide and there are descriptions in the docs but these don't help at all.  where am I supposed to get a list of "alternative" (private and public) name servers?
2. VPC network list cannot be provided because I'm trying to create a VPC, ergo none yet exist.  so it seems like a catch-22: I cannot create a policy without a VPC, and I cannot create a VPC without a policy.  grr...
3. can anyone recommend where I might find a GCP admin/consultant?

TIA -- ekkis

Comment: What type of DNS Policy are you trying to create? The command in your question is generic. For example, are you trying to create an "inbound forwarding" policy? Note: You can create DNS policies after the VPC is created. What document are you referring to where you mention "Step 8". Google publishes a list of experts: https://developers.google.com/community/experts/directory I am on that list.

Comment: having to create a DNS policy is just a nuisance to me.  so  I don't know what type I need to create.  I just know that the guide I'm following doesn't cover this point and I can't proceed without it

as for the document I'm following, it's found on the console.cloud.google.com under "Getting Started".  there's a button "Go to the checklist"

Comment: thanks for the experts directory but it doesn't cover GCP.  Workspace is as close as it gets.  however, I'll reach out to some of the people and maybe they can recommend

Comment: Google has experts for Google Cloud Platform. In the "Technology" selection dropdown box select "Google Cloud Platform". You can also select the region.